# Sufficient Condition for inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

I've been working on a problem and I found that a necessary and sufficient condition for the result I want is the following

$$f'\bigg(\frac{x}{k+1}\bigg)-f'\bigg(\frac{x}{k}\bigg)<f'\bigg(\frac{1-x}{k+2}\bigg)-f'\bigg(\frac{1-x}{k+1}\bigg)$$

Where $x\in[0,1]$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $f>0$, $f'>0$ and $f''<0$. I am looking for a sufficient condition for this equation to hold, independent of $x$ and $k$.

I am really stuck with it and don't know how to proceed, so any advice is welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-You have the function $f$ that on $[0,1]$ satisfies your conditions$$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(2x)+6x}{4}\gt0\\f'(x)=\frac{\cos(2x)+3}{2}\gt0\\f''(x)=-\sin(2x)\lt0$$ and you can verify that
$$f'\left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right)-f'\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)\lt f'\left(\frac{x-1}{k+2}\right)-f'\left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right)$$ but not for $0\le x\le 1$ but      for $x\gt1$.

Can this perhaps,by appropriate modification, help you in your problem?